# Tracking multiple iPhone GPS locations live

Tags: ios, core-location, gamekit

When developing an application like Find my friends, when you can see multiple people on a map move live (say, in a defined area like the beach or a park), what is the key technologies to use ? I was thinking GameKit to pair devices instead of passing through a central server, which might be slower. But is GameKit really doing peer to peer connectivity ? What maximum distance will allow this ? Is there another better way to track position live ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameKit may not work - due to limitations with Bluetooth range which is typically 30-40 feet

You may want to consider a remote server that processes the locations from the various clients and clients get the other client locations from the server.

Comment: ok, I was affraid of that. Do you have any advice regarding transmitting the geolocation data in an efficient way ? Ideally it's sent fast and then broadcasted to devices, but I guess that the device really should pull... Also, it's impossible to make this app work while the phone screen is off ?

Comment: You can get location updated when running in the background. I think it will be fast enough depending on the cellular data connectivity speed. The clients can poll the sever when the user goes to the screen to see their friends location .. (pls do vote up / accept the answer)

Comment: I know about the location background task, but is it possible/allowed to send the location data to a server every time the app gets it in the background ?

Comment: There are no restrictions on sending data to server in background. You can optimize by sending only when there is relevant / noticeable location change say 50 meters or so..

Comment: The point is to track live movement (player will be running at each other). thanks for your help !